# EC2 - Fresh PHP install - Mail not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, lamp, sendmail, php

I am getting familiar with Amazons EC2. I installed a LAMP setup but when I try to send emails through the mail() function that I have in my pages it does not work. I checked and sendmail is running and is on the phpinfo page.

I have tried changing the php.ini sendmail_from and it does nothing. SMTP port is open on the firewall... im freakin lost..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This won't directly solve your issue (edit: I mean the error message you have now edited out), but Amazon EC2 instances have a really spotty mail reputation.  You're probably going to have deliverability issues.

Thankfully [Amazon created the Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to go along with EC2, with a free level of service for EC2 customers.  The API is pretty simple and there are transport adapters for many excellent PHP mailing libraries, like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) ([transport](https://github.com/jmhobbs/Swiftmailer-Transport--AWS-SES)).

Comment: I don't even think you *can* send emails from their servers.

Answer (score 7):

Please install sendmail extension,  I solved this issue just by installing sendmail in my instance.

Just type: sudo apt-get install sendmail 
in your terminal.

That worked for me