# PHP - EC2 Implementing SES - Help

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, sendmail, postfix-mta

Hey Guys. I have my servers setup via EC2. I had postfix setup but as usual the emails were going into the spam box. I signed up for Amazons SES, i see everyone saying its easy to implement although I cannot seem to figure it out.

I downloaded the PHP SDK and put it in a inc folder. refrenced it in my script. and I cannot get any response what-so-ever from the script. Is there any demo scrips I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*"Wow,"* I thought to myself.  *"This is just **the** night for questions for which [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is a great answer!  Why, I was just recommending it for someone on EC2 that may have needed SES [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292170/ec2-fresh-php-install-mail-not-working/5292296#5292296)!  What luck, I can jus-- **WAIT A MINUTE**, this is the same guy!"*

In all seriousness, though, I can't really recommend Amazon's SDK.  It's not bad code, mind you, but the documentation for it is spread out all over the place.

[This third-party Transport addon for SwiftMailer](https://github.com/jmhobbs/Swiftmailer-Transport--AWS-SES) uses it's own implementation of the API calls, and just needs your AWS key  and secret.  [Here's a blog post by the author showing how to use it](http://www.velvetcache.org/2011/01/25/swiftmailer-transport-for-amazon-simple-email-service) to send mail out.  This needs to happen *after* you [authenticate the to/from email addresses](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?InitialSetup.EmailVerification.html) for your testing.

Comment: Charles, You have been very helpful today! I have downloaded swiftmailer via pear, and also downloaded the transport addon. I finally got a response!! It said I need to verify that email before I can send mail, I looked through the addon for a function to do so and I cannot find one. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check out the very last link in my post above -- it's a link to the documentation about verifying/authorizing/authenticating the sending address.